# Regex matching in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in Java that I need to split using `"<$"` and `"$>"` as delimiters.
But if I have something looking like `"\<$something_we_dont_care_what$>"` than we ignore it and move on.

I've been trying to write a regex doing this for a while but I keep failing and reading about regular expressions in Java is just making me more and more confused...

Can anyone tell me the right way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Show actual code that does not work.

Comment: stackoverflow removed the actual delimiters but lets pretend they are ($ and $) and when we have \($something$) it shouldnt be recognized as delimiter

Comment: @user1276405 - StackOverflow didn't remove anything.  You got the markup incorrect.  Read the "Help" on Markdown ... see that orange questionmark icon when you are editting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.
I've found a solution after a few hours of browsing and experimenting.
Regex expression that does exactly what I wanted is following:

```
// char $ needs to be escaped because it has different meaning in regular expressions
// <$
String leftDelimiter = "(<\\$)";
// $>
String rightDelimiter = "(\\$>)";

// leftDelimiter | rightDelimiter
// when used to split a string would split it each time it detected those two patters
// and it would also split it in the case I dont want them to split it
// and that is "\<$foo$>" case - when they are "escaped" in the string

// to solve it we can try to match our leftDelimiter only if char \ isnt before it

// matches all [$ that dont start with \
String fixedLeftDelimiter = "(?<!\\\\)"+leftDelimiter;

// the problem presents itself with the rightDelimiter because it needs to check 
// whether there had been a leftDelimiter before it that has been escaped


// the following takes care of that

// matches all $> that dont have a <$ starting with \
String betterRightDelimiter = "(?<!\\\\"+leftDelimiter+whatCanBeInTags+rightDelimiter;

// whatCanBeInTags is everything that can be in out tags besides $ sign
// we are using {0,"+(Integer.MAX_VALUE-3)+"}? instead of *? because of a limitation
// of number of characters put in lookbehind assertion
String whatCanBeInTags = "[^\\$]{0,"+(Integer.MAX_VALUE-3)+"}?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you have two strings - not in your code, but read from file or a JTextField:

```
s = "\<$foo$>";
p = "[^\\]?<\$[^\$]*\$>";
```

And you want to match the pattern to the String.

What I have done so far:

- A group, which does not contain a backslash `[^\\]?` but might be optional.
- `<$`, where the Dollar, as special regex has to be masked by a backslash, as the backslash before.
- A group `[^\$]*` which does not contain another Dollar of free length.
- A Dollar with `\$>` a greater-than. Again: Dollar masked.

A question for your domain is, whether the foo-part, or something_we_dont_care_what, might contain a dollar sign, not followed by a `>`. I asssumed not.

```
  s.match (p);
```

Should now return true or false, but the problem is, how to get it into your code. The problem is, that not only regex, but Java itself treats the backslash as masking character. So you have to double each of them:

```
p = "[^\\\\]?<\\$[^\\$]*\\$>";
```

If the test case is a literal text in your code too, this applies for it too:

```
"\\<$foo$>".matches (p);
```

Trying them out is often a good idea if you have a tool where you can omit the Java masking first - a simple GUI with two JTextFields, or code which reads the pattern from a properties file, which saves you from repeated recompiles.

```
public class PM
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        String bad = "\\<$foo$>";
        String good = "<$foo$>";
        String p = "[^\\\\]?<\\$[^\\$]*\\$>";
        System.out.println ("bad:\t" + bad.matches (p));
        System.out.println ("good:\t" + good.matches (p));
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole problem that while this works when used with String matches method it doesn't when used with split.

Comment: And on the side note I need it to match "<?" and "?>" (not "<?foo?>") unless "<?" is backslashed ("\<?") in which case it's supposed to ignore the whole "\<?foo?>"

Comment: Well, you might have "a<$b$>c", and want to split it into a,b,c? Except, if a ends with backslash. But you don't want to match "a<$b<$c" or "a$>b$>c". So I guess you have to do two matches - the first to check for the whole expression, and a second one to split it.